# Googlemaps API: problems getting property k

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In win form project i use WebBrowser control. I assign DocumentText property to html file. in file i have link to Google Maps API's like this:

```
<script 
    type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=****&sensor=false" />.
```

All works good . But after any time i got error:

```
Line: 99
Error: Unable to get property 'k' of undefined or null reference.
```

In my javascript code i don't use property 'k'. please help, what's the problem,I can't fix problem. In javascript code i use Google API's features.

Comment: In which file is the error? Can you post the relevant code part from this file?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Property k in the google maps api is one of the values it uses internally. Your code is breaking before it gets there though, you've forgotten to initialize or get some object before using it.

In JavaScript this is complicated by the fact that you can get this kind of error in cases where you have code like

```
foo.bar.props['example'].things
```

and you'll get an error about trying to access property 'things' if foo is undefined or null.